# xcopy command and winrar files

Tags: windows, xcopy

I am new to cmd commands and am having a problem with the xcopy command

The command:

```
xcopy /e E:\ C:\testFolder\
```

Doesn't work. It would copy files but would stop when copying winrar files(.gz)
What I am trying to do is to copy all the contents in my usb flash drive to the destination folder. The command will halt when the winrar files are next to be copied. The cmd prompt would just keep on blinking. It is a 17 MB file.

What is the transfer speed of xcopy?  How long would a 17MB file be copied through xcopy?

---

Ok, the transfer speed depends on my hardware. What about the command "freezing"?

Comment: Totally depends on the speed of your HDD and USB drive.

Comment: The `xcopy` command does not have any arbitrary limitations on transfer speed. How long it takes will be entirely dependent upon your setup. But it should take no more time than a copy in Windows Explorer.

Comment: The [command prompt](http://homepage.ntlworld.com./jonathan.deboynepollard/FGA/command-prompts.html) does not blink.  The _cursor_ blinks, and its blinking does _not_ mean that `xcopy` has "frozen".  The blinking of the cursor has nothing whatsoever to do with the action of `xcopy`, in fact.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
xcopy E:\ C:\testFolder\ /e /c
```

and regarding the transfer rate! i think it would be the 12Mbit/s if it is USB 2.0